# Is it possible to write a function signature that behaves like getattr()'s does?

Tags: python, signature, built-in

According to `help(getattr)`, two or three arguments are accepted:

```
getattr(...)
    getattr(object, name[, default]) -> value
```

Doing some simple tests, we can confirm this:

```
>>> obj = {}
>>> getattr(obj, 'get')
<built-in method get of dict object at 0x7f6d4beaf168>
>>> getattr(obj, 'bad', 'with default')
'with default'
```

Too few/too many arguments also behave as expected:

```
>>> getattr()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: getattr expected at least 2 arguments, got 0
>>> getattr(obj, 'get', 'with default', 'extra')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: getattr expected at most 3 arguments, got 4
```

The argument names specified in the help text do not seem to be accepted as keyword arguments:

```
>>> getattr(object=obj, name='get')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: getattr() takes no keyword arguments
```

The `inspect` module is no help here:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getargspec(getattr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 816, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
TypeError: <built-in function getattr> is not a Python function

(messaging is a little different in python3, but the gist is the same)
```

Now, the question: Is there a straightforward way to write my own Python function with a signature that behaves exactly like `getattr`'s signature? That is, keyword arguments are not allowed, and minumum/maximum number of arguments are enforced? The closest I've come is the following:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    len_args = len(args)
    if len_args < 2:
        raise TypeError('expected at least 2 arguments, got %d' % len_args)
    elif len_args > 3:
        raise TypeError('expected at most 3 arguments, got %d' % len_args)
    ...
```

But now instead of meaningful argument names like `object` and `name` we get `args[0]` and `args[1]`. It's also a lot of boilerplate, and feels downright unpleasant. I know that, being a builtin, `getattr` must have vastly different implementation than typical Python code, and perhaps there's no way to perfectly emulate the way it behaves. But it's a curiosity I've had for a while.

Comment: @Makoto: Not a duplicate; optional arguments are easy, but this question is specifically looking for positional-only argument behavior as well.

Answer (score 3):

As of Python 3.8, there is now syntax-level support for this:

```
def f(a, b, c=None, /):
    ...
```

Note the slash. Any parameters before the slash are *positional-only*; they cannot be specified by keyword. This syntax has been picked out for quite a while - [PEP 457](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0457/) dates back to 2013 - but it was only made an actual language feature in Python 3.8.

Regardless of whether any parameters are made positional-only, default argument values still have the limitation that there is no way to distinguish the no-value-passed case from the case where the default is passed explicitly. To do that, you have to process `*args` manually.

---

Prior to Python 3.8, these kinds of function signatures are particular to functions written in C, using the C-level [`PyArg_Parse*`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html) family of functions and the [Argument Clinic](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html) preprocessor. There's no built-in way to write that kind of signature in Python before 3.8. The closest you can get is what you already came up with, using `*args`.

Comment: @martineau: As far as I'm aware, the closest you can get is to parse `*args` manually, which is what the questioner already came up with.

Comment: Yes, but the way they're doing it may not the simplest. For the particular example in their question, seems to me like a simple `def myfunc(obj, name, default=None):` would suffice—although they would need to replace the `None` with some sort of unique value if it was a legal argument value. This is also easy to do...

Comment: @martineau: They're specifically looking to replicate positional-only argument behavior, not just optional arguments. Optional arguments are easy.

Comment: In that case a `def myfunc(obj, name, *args):` with a check in the body to make sure the length of `args` was `1` would seem meet most of the OP's requirements.

Comment: Giving a +1 to this, especially for the links. Some good reading in there.

Answer (score 3):

This code ticks most of your requirements:

```
def anonymise_args(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrap(*args):
        return fn(*args)
    return wrap


@anonymise_args
def myfunc(obj, name, default=None):
    print obj, name, default
```

- keyword arguments are not allowed

  ```
  x.myfunc(obj=1, name=2)
  TypeError: wrap() got an unexpected keyword argument 'obj'
  ```
- A minumum/maximum number of arguments are enforced

  ```
  x.myfunc(1,2,3,4)
  TypeError: myfunc() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
  ```
- meaningful argument names
- not a lot of boilerplate

Comment: Did you leave out `functools.wraps` in your tests? The first error message doesn't look right.

Comment: Also, you should probably `return` in `wrap` to correctly pass through return values when wrapping functions with meaningful return values.

Comment: 1) I did include `functools.wraps` in my tests. I don't know why the error message includes `wrap()`. 2) Yes, `wrap` should include `return`.

Comment: [Apparently it's using the code object's `co_name` instead of the function object's `__name__`, so it still gets the original name.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4a8bcdf79cdb3684743fe1268de62ee88bada439/Python/ceval.c#L4014)

Comment: That reusability is nice. I especially like how I get to rely on the default value pattern, which is readable and familiar.